# conda prevent python upgrade on windows

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, conda

**EDIT**

---

official python 2.7.11 installer from python.org has a major bug (`PyInitialize` from embedded CPython causes hard crash) which can be avoided by following instructions in this bug report:

https://bugs.python.org/issue25824

---

**ORIGINAL**

Is it possible to prevent conda to update python on windows when installing new packages? The problem is that I need to use official CPython installation.

e.g.

```
conda install numba
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .........

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Python\Python27_32b:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.11              |                4        22.3 MB
    enum34-1.1.2               |           py27_0          54 KB
    funcsigs-0.4               |           py27_0          19 KB
    numpy-1.10.4               |           py27_0         2.8 MB
    llvmlite-0.10.0            |           py27_0         4.6 MB
    numexpr-2.5.1              |      np110py27_0         141 KB
    scipy-0.17.0               |      np110py27_0        10.8 MB
    numba-0.25.0               |      np110py27_0         1.6 MB
    scikit-learn-0.17.1        |      np110py27_0         3.3 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        45.5 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    enum34:       1.1.2-py27_0
    funcsigs:     0.4-py27_0
    llvmlite:     0.10.0-py27_0
    numba:        0.25.0-np110py27_0
    pip:          8.1.1-py27_1
    python:       2.7.11-4

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    numexpr:      2.5.1-np111py27_0  --> 2.5.1-np110py27_0
    scikit-learn: 0.17.1-np111py27_0 --> 0.17.1-np110py27_0
    scipy:        0.17.0-np111py27_0 --> 0.17.0-np110py27_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    numpy:        1.11.0-py27_0      --> 1.10.4-py27_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: @EdisonGustavoMuenz look at the list of packages to be downloaded and installed above - it includes python 2.7.11, build 4. This is Anaconda custom compilation of CPython without debug symbols. The debug symbols are only provided with Anaconda Enterprise edition for ~10K USD. Without debug symbols it is not possible to do cross-language debugging with PTVS.

Comment: I found that numpy, scipy, sklearn do not work without cpython from anaconda, hence ended up installing unofficial wheels.

Comment: Oh now I understand, sorry.

Comment: The latest build of python 2.7.11 includes the debug symbols...

Comment: @IanH I just located these symbols (.pdb) in anaconda installation, thank you for this update!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to actually prevent conda from installing new Python? I understand that you solved your immediate problem differently, but this idiotic behavior is really upsetting...